# Change default 'Print to File' settings

Tags: printing, pdf

How can I change the default settings for 'Print to File' in the Print dialogue?

I would like to change the default save location from ~/ to ~/Desktop.

p.s. I **do not** want to have to use cups-pdf

Answer (score 1):

#### Thunderbird

In Mozilla Thunderbird, go to Edit > Preferences, select the Advanced panel, select the General tab, and click Config Editor.

Search for `print_to_filename` and adjust the property.

[image]

You you fill confident, search for `print.` and change other settings as well.

I've changed:

- `print.print_paper_name` to `iso-a4`
- `print.print_paper_height` to `297`
- `print.print_paper_width` to `210`

#### Firefox

Just open `about:config` page and search for the same settings.
You don't have to restart the applications to use the new settings.

#### Units

There are several measurements used in the settings, like `print.print_paper_height` or `print.print_paper_width`.

To use **millimeters**, set `print_paper_size_unit` is set to 1. To use **inches**, set `print_paper_size_unit` is set to 0.

Comment: In Thunderbird 78 it is called print.print_to_filename

Answer (score -1):

Print to File.  Dialogue box look for the 'Save in Folder' drop down and then choose the location you would like to save it, if its not listed click on the 'other'.  Simple really.